# If AC is false , is this statement about the halting problem true?

Tags: axiom-of-choice, axioms, conjectures, peano-axioms, stopping-times

Assume AC is false.
(AC = axiom of choice )

Let $n,m$ be positive integers. Let $f: \Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb N$ and $f(m)=m$.

- Let $g(n,m)=1$ if the iterations $f(n),f(f(n)),...$ converges to $m$.
- If $g(n,m)=1$, let $G(n,g)=x$ be the (min) amount of iterations needed to arrive at $m$.

Statement : If one can prove that $g(n,m)=1$ for all $n$ then one can prove an upper boundary  $T(n)$ for $G(n,g)$.

For example if one could prove Collatz :

$g(n,1)=1$ is true for all $n$ <=> Collatz is true.

$\implies G(n,g) < T(n)$ and $T(n)$ equals (for example) $2^{2^{2^n}}$

This statement comes from someone I know, and I was not able to find a counterexample.
Im not sure if this statement is a named conjecture or theorem yet.

And I do not know if its true of course.

I do know however that ZFC is required to prove Goodstein's theorem and there is no upper bound known for $G(n,g)$ here.  So I think if AC is true then the statement is false.

I considered this statement to be an axiom too , but that would mean it cannot be proved or disproved which I doubt. But who knows.

Comment: Someone voted for close. May I ask why ?

Comment: The vote was for "unclear what you're asking". Could you please try and reformulate more clearly the question? Now it's too similar to a conjecture about a conjecture on a conjecture.

Comment: Although In my opinion it was clear enough , it could have been clearer. By Tomi's suggested and accepted edit, this has now been achieved. Thanks @Tomi. And thanks egreg for the reconsideration.

Comment: No problem, this is really clear for me, but I don not know the answer (the question is really good).
If you want, please read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that using $f$ as an additional symbol, one can write the definition of $g$ as a first-order statement, as well the definition of $G$ (note that $g$ is not really a variable, because $g$ itself is definable from $f$).

The statement, if so, about $T(n)$, is all but a first-order statement in the augmented language of the natural numbers.

Shoenfield's absoluteness theorem tells us that first-order statements (and even simple second-order statements) are absolute between any two models of $\sf ZF$ which have the same ordinals. That is, the statement is true in one model if and only if it is true in another.

Now, if $V$ is any model of $\sf ZF$ then $L\subseteq V$ is an inner model of $V$ satisfying the axiom of choice, so if the statement is provable from $\sf ZFC$ then it is true in $L$, and by absoluteness, it is true in $V$ as well.

Comment: So you are saying it is independant of AC ?
And is it (dis)provable ?

Comment: No, I'm saying that *if* it is provable from $\sf ZFC$ then it is provable from $\sf ZF$ as well, and the axiom of choice has absolutely no effect on the truth value of this sort of statements.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think the statement is decidable ?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: That is surprising. It seemed like a natural question to me. Consider it a compliment ;)

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. I should point out that it's very easy to find a lot of very natural questions that are very hard to answer. Let alone in the field of number theory. The trick is to find interesting, and hard questions, which can be answered -- and the answer too.

Comment: Perhaps this is getting a bit too chatty, But intresting and hard are not mathematically defined. In fact hard sounds to me like needing education to even understand the question. But this may not be what you meant. As for my opinion , I think only FLT and a few others serve as an exemple. But who am I ...